# Does Pig have a shuffle function?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The question I have is is there an in build function in pig to shuffle a tuple/bag ?

```
raw_record = LOAD '$inputPath' -- USING com.test.parser.TestParser;
record_project = FOREACH raw_record GENERATE
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      field4;

sl_record = FILTER record_project BY (field1=='1' OR field1=='2');
split sl_record into rec1 if field1=='1',rec2 if field1=='2';
rec2Sample = SAMPLE rec2 $samplingRate;
finalRec1 = FOREACH rec1 GENERATE
      -1,
      1,
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      field4;

finalRec2 = FOREACH rec2 GENERATE
      1,
      1,
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      field4;

unionRec = UNION finalRec1, finalRec2; 
STORE unionRec INTO '$outputPath' USING PigStorage(',');
```

In the above example the problem is with the union, I see all of finalRec1 followed by all finalRec2. I need this to be shuffled or mixed.

The approach I took to solve it is :

```
raw_record = LOAD '$inputPath' -- USING com.test.parser.TestParser;
record_project = FOREACH raw_record GENERATE
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      field4;

sl_record = FILTER record_project BY (field1=='1' OR field1=='2');
split sl_record into rec1 if field1=='1',rec2 if field1=='2';
rec2Sample = SAMPLE rec2 $samplingRate;
finalRec1 = FOREACH rec1 GENERATE
      -1,
      1,
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      field4,
      (chararray)RANDOM() AS id;

finalRec2 = FOREACH rec2 GENERATE
      1,
      1,
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      field4,
      (chararray)RANDOM() AS id;

unionRec = UNION finalRec1, finalRec2;
mixedRec = ORDER unionRec BY id ASC
STORE mixedRec INTO '$outputPath' USING PigStorage(',');
```

This way I was able to mix them but now I'm unable to write a pig unit test. Is there a way I can shuffle unionRec directly and also write a pig unit test?

Test :

```
@Test
public void myPigUnitTest {
    String []inputs=new String[] {
        "inputPath=/src/test/resource/testFile.txt",
        "samplingRate=1",
        "outputPath=dummy"
    };
    PigTest pigTest = PigUnitUtil.createPigTest("pathToMyPigFile",inputs);
    String [] expectedUnion;
    String [] expectedMixedRec;
    pigTest.assertOutput("unionRec",expectedUnion);
    pigTest.assertOutput("mixedRec",expectedMixedRec);
}
```

Here the problem is that the unionRec and mixedRec have random number as well as there order for mixed is messed up.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the _unit test_ part? Why cannot you write one?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz the problem is random part which cannot be determined. I'll update the question with my unit test too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to think of a work around myself :

```
raw_record = LOAD '$inputPath' -- USING com.test.parser.TestParser;
record_project = FOREACH raw_record GENERATE
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      field4;

sl_record = FILTER record_project BY (field1=='1' OR field1=='2');
split sl_record into rec1 if field1=='1',rec2 if field1=='2';
rec2Sample = SAMPLE rec2 $samplingRate;
finalRec1 = FOREACH rec1 GENERATE
      -1 as label1,
      1 as label2,
      field1  as label3,
      field2 as label4,
      field3 as label5,
      field4  as label6;

finalRec2 = FOREACH rec2 GENERATE
      -1 as label1,
      1 as label2,
      field1  as label3,
      field2 as label4,
      field3 as label5,
      field4  as label6;

unionRec = UNION finalRec1, finalRec2;
unionRecWithId = FOREACH unionRec GENERATE label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6,(chararray)RANDOM() AS id;
mixedRec = ORDER unionRecWithId by id ASC;
STORE mixedRec INTO '$outputPath' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Now I verify unionRec if it has all the data as expected.

Comment: I don't think you need ORDER at the end. Group by should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Once the tuples have been shuffled, project the columns to drop `id` and call [assertOutputAnyOrder](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/trunk/test/org/apache/pig/pigunit/PigTest.java#L370):

> Compares the expected results to the results of the last alias generated in the script. Order does not matter and as long as the result is located in any index of expected and any line of the output then this will pass.